# RavenDB Load aggregate returns an empty instance

Tags: ravendb

What would I need to be doing wrong to get an aggregate to be returned from the session (loading by id) that is an empty instance of the aggregate and not the entire graph. When I hit the actual url that is requested in my browser I see the full json object, hence, why I am suspicious of my session management.

I have tried recreating the situation in unit tests but no manner of poor session management can recreate what I am seeing. I see some null instances returned but never this strange 'empty' instance - which has an id but none of the properties have been hydrated.

I am seeing this behaviour in unstable build 438.

*I just checked the behaviour by executing a query and am seeing the same issue, so it is not just when calling Load()*

Comment: Maybe you played with the serializer? http://ravendb.net/documentation/docs-custom-serialization

Comment: Can you post some code showing what you call the misuse of session? also, it may be a bit easier to do on our mailing list

Comment: I tried to simulate session abuse in my unit tests to attempt to get insight into what I may be doing in my app. Nothing I did could recreate this empty object instance. (And I thought maybe the serializer as well - but if I start a fresh session around my load it works as expected).

I guess I was just looking into some insight as to what situation could return this strange instance in Raven. At that point I may have some further clues as to what I am doing wrong ;)

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing symptoms similar to those that I presented in the original question - the most likely scenario is that you are loading the entity via a 'stale' session.

I discovered that due to some IoC container config flaws on my behalf (remember, singletons are bad kiddies) that I was attempting to load via a session that had been hanging around far too long. I can't determine whether it had been disposed or not (I suspect not) but it was definitely living well past its creation date.

I am not sure this exactly explains the behaviour I was seeing, but I present it here in the hope of helping others.